# How to change the order of attributes in the Ubertcart cart page

Tags: 7, ubercart

In the screenshot, you can see that the attributes for this product are listed in seemingly random order.  Actually, it seems to be ordered by the attribute ID.  Is there a way to change this order?  Each attribute has a "List position" property but this only seems to be for the product page, it doesn't affect the cart.

[image]

Comment: Are you using D6 or D7?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Drupal 7.23 with UberCart 7.x-3.5.

Comment: change order of field display under content type manage display settings.

Comment: Hi @ARUN, thanks for the answer but that doesn't seem to be the solution.  That only lets you change the order of the fields in the catalog or teaser view, but what I need is to change the order of the product attributes in the shopping cart.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at ubdercart's [theme_uc_attribute_add_to_cart](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ubercart!uc_attribute!uc_attribute.theme.inc/function/theme_uc_attribute_add_to_cart/7) function and how it is themeing the output including attributes, it appears that you can achieve what you want by implementing `hook_form_alter`. I would start by finding the `form_id`, perhaps by adding a debug statement in the function. Then I would implement hook_form_alter and would alter the way the attributes are ordered to my desired order.
If this does do what you want, try and follow the logic to see where the attributes are being themed and/or built. Then hook into that mechanism (`form_alter` or a preprocess function) and  I am confident you will achieve what you want. 
Hope this helps.